# the decryptNode function for leaf nodes in CP-ABE

Tags: encryption, pairings, abe

Can someone please explain to me why decryptNode gives as result $e(g,g)^rq(0)$ for leaf nodes, I don't understand how they went from the second step to the third (here is the article: [Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~bwaters/publications/papers/cp-abe.pdf)), also note that there is an error in the second step, it's $g^q(0)$ and not $h^q(0)$

[image: decryptNode for leaf nodes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H$ is a hash that projects into $\mathbb{G}_0$, one must be able to write $H(i)$ as $g^z$ for some unknown $z$, because $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{G}_0$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{DecryptNode(CT,SK,}x\text{)} & = & \frac{e(D_i, C_x)}{e(D^{'}_i, C^{'}_x)} \\
& = & \frac{e(g^r\cdot H(i)^{r_i}, g^{q_x(0)})}{e(g^{r_i}, H(i)^{q_x(0)})} \\
& = & \frac{e(g^r, g^{q_x(0)})\cdot e(H(i)^{r_i}, g^{q_x(0)})}{e(g^{r_i}, H(i)^{q_x(0)})} \\
& = & \frac{e(g^r, g^{q_x(0)})\cdot e(g^{z r_i}, g^{q_x(0)})}{e(g^{r_i}, g^{z{q_x(0)}})} \\
& = & \frac{e(g, g)^{r{q_x(0)}}\cdot e(g, g)^{z r_i {q_x(0)}}}{e(g, g)^{r_i z{q_x(0)}}} \\
& = & e(g, g)^{r{q_x(0)}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

The last step works because $e(g, g)^a\cdot e(g, g)^{-a} = 1$.