# tripartite diffie hellman with Weil pairing

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

I try to understand how the tripartite Diffie-Hellman key exchange works.
I read Joux's paper for this: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-One-Round-Protocol-for-Tripartite-Diffie-Hellman-Joux/845e96c20e5a5ff3b03f4caf72c3cb817a7fa542/pdf

However on page 388 he states the following equality which I don't see why it is true:
$F_W(a,P_b,Q_c) = F_W(a,Q_b, P_c)$

where $F_W(x,y,z)= e_m(y,z)^x$.
For me the first value of the equality is the inverse of the second one?

Answer (score 2):

This does indeed appear to be a typo. Using that $e_m$ is bilinear and alternating, one calculates
$$\begin{align*}
F_W(a,P_b,Q_c)
\;&=\; e_m([b]P,[c]Q)^a
\\&=\; e_m(P,Q)^{abc}
\\&=\; e_m(Q,P)^{-abc}
\\&=\; e_m([b]Q,[c]P)^{-a}
\\&=\; F_W(a,Q_b,P_c)^{-1}
\text.
\end{align*}$$

(However, note that these are only different if the order of $e_m(P,Q))$ does not divide $abc$; in particular, we need $e_m(P,Q)\neq1$.)

Comment: thank you! that's exactly what I thought! for the second part of your answer notice that P and Q are supposed to be independant ,hence the Weil pairing of these two points is a primitive root of unity.

Comment: I don't see that this is true. Is $e_m(P,Q)=e_m(Q,P)^{-1}$ some inherent property of the Weil pairing? Can you clarify this step?

Comment: yes this property can be shown to be true for every point of m-torsion. This is called the alternating property. see here: https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/elliptic/weil.html

Comment: I see. So, does this mean that my answer [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31025/13022) is wrong? The trick I've used there would also be applicable to this question and would mean that the equality is actually true.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I suppose that by "trick", you refer to writing $H(i)$ as a power of $g$? In that case, the same method is not applicable here: The points $P$ and $Q$ are assumed to be independent, i.e., $e_m(P,Q)\neq1$, and this implies they are not a multiple of the same point by the properties of the Weil pairing.