# DecryptNode for non-leaf Node in CP-ABE

Tags: abe, identity-based-encryption

I've looked at paper [Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Ebwaters/publications/papers/cp-abe.pdf) by Bethencourt, Sahai, Waters and see this an [answer here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30987/the-decryptnode-function-for-leaf-nodes-in-cp-abe) for the explanation of `DecrypNode` for a leaf node.

I could understand the derivation of this $f_n$ for a leaf node but not for a non-leaf node in the $s$.

I could not understand the move from **step 4 to 5** ( the last move).

I will be very grateful Can somebody help in understanding the last move here?

How
**qx(0) = qx(1) /*\1(0) . qx(2) /*\2(0) . qx(3) /_\3(0)** . ...  ?

I don't think Lagrange interpolation says this. I think I am missing something here. Please help me in understanding this.

Thanks and Regards

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Your question is not clear. Could you post a link?

Comment: It is 11 months ago. Maybe you can delete this and ask again in a better way...

Answer (score 0):

The last two steps is from Lagrange interpolation such that $\sum_{i\in S_x'} q_x(i)\triangle_{i,S_x'}(0)=q_x(0)$. The concept is the same as that of leaf node, but now we are at the parent node. Doing this recursively up to the root node would give the secret exponent.